# Using Python to remove the unordered lists that do not have unordered sublists in Markdown

Tags: python, markdown

Firstly, see how it looks like in Markdown:

```markdown
# Known

* Languages with Latin alphabet:
  * English
  * French
  * Portuguese

* Languages with Greek alphabet:
  * Greek

* Languages with Armenian alphabet:

* Languages with Ethiopic script:

* Languages with Tamil script:

* Languages with Hiragana characters:
  * Japanese

* Languages with Klingon script:

# Wanted

**These wanted languages:**

* Languages with Sumero-Akkadian script:

* Languages with Hangul characters:
  * Korean

* Languages with Linear A script:
```

Observe attentively that these that are without sublists or are with a new line should be removed, together with a new line.

I attempted to use the regular expressions and the `^$\n` to remove the lines. I left the comments to you to understand better:

```py
file_name = "Language support"

def remove_empty_lists():
  # It will read the file
  with open("{}.md".format(file_name), "r") as f:
    # It will search all the lines of the whole text
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:

      # It will find all the lines that contain "* Language with ..."
      if re.search(r"\* Languages with", line):
       # then if these contained lines have the symbol ":"
        if re.search(r":$", line):
        # It will find the empy new line
          if re.search(r"^$\n", line):
            # Then finally it will remove the list and the new line
            lines.remove(line)
  # It will rewrite the same file
  with open("{}.md".format(file_name), "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
      f.write(line)
```

I was expecting that it should look like:

```markdown
# Known

* Languages with Latin alphabet:
  * English
  * French
  * Portuguese

* Languages with Greek alphabet:
  * Greek

* Languages with Hiragana characters:
  * Japanese

# Wanted

**These wanted languages:**

* Languages with Hangul characters:
  * Korean
```

It was what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you do simply the opposite: You write an regular expression to find the things you want not the things you don't want.

You might want to use this website for easy creating regex. For example if you want to keep new lines or other parts of the file you can make the regex match these too. https://coding.tools/regex-replace

```
import re
file_name = "md.md"

# regex of things we want to keep
regex = re.compile(r"^\*\s.*\n([ \t]+.*\n)+", re.MULTILINE)

with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    # read all of the file, not line by line
    lines = f.read()

    clean_file = ""
    for res in regex.findall(lines):
        clean_file += res

    print(clean_file)
```

output is

```
* Languages with Latin alphabet:
  * English
* Languages with Greek alphabet:
  * Greek
* Languages with Hiragana characters:
  * Japanese
* Languages with Hangul characters:
  * Korean
```

[image]

Comment: I tested your regular expression in Regex 101, it appears that my original text uses tab and that text shown here up uses space. I am sorry, I thought that I was using space. You can check: https://regex101.com/r/prvkbb/1 and you can view the render whitespaces.

Comment: I kept testing until that I found the solution: `^\*\s.*\n[^\t]`

Comment: I tried both `^\*\s.*\n[^\t]` and `^\*\sIdiomas.*\n(?!\t)`. They worked on Regex 101 and Regex Coding Tool, but did not work on the terminal. Both removed accidentally the full lists. I do not know why.

Comment: Hi, i updated the regex to support tabs (see image) and spaces. If this works for you, I'd be happy if you accept/upvote my answer :-) Good luck!